# How can I set size of css-content-image?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

```
.upper-menu .search-form::after {
  content: url('../images/search.png');
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  right: 22px;
}
```

I have pseudo-element that looks like this. I would like to change the size of the image by scaling it down 50% so that it works on high-res-screens as well. How can I do this?

Comment: try `background-size: 10px 5px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also, you could set the content to empty string and use a background image. Just alternatively...

```
.upper-menu .search-form::after {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #bada55 url("img_2x.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  right: 22px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to set the width and height property to 50%. This will scale it according to the browser window.

Good Luck!

Comment: Actually it will scale relative to `.search-form`, not the browser window.

Comment: actually, it would scale to exactly the dimensions specified -- ie 10px.

Comment: actually, it won't. Y'all realize the question is about using a `url()` image in `content` of an `:after` pseudo element, right?  If you can make that work, how about a demo snippet?